# Static website in Google Cloud - how to set mainpage (when index.html is in a different folder)

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I just joined. I created a bucket for my static website. The index.html (or mainpage per google terminology) is in a different folder in the same bucket. I set my index.html as the page to show up automatically (www.example.com)

I get the website on my browser if i type exact http url including my file name - IT WORKS.  But, if i type the  domain name alone on the browser, i get the following error:

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

I did setup my MainPage on the bucket options.  HEre is my gsutil web get.
{"mainPageSuffix": "gs://www.example.co/NewHome/index.html"}

But index.html does not show up when i type only example.co in the browser. Any suggestions???

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer the path is relative to home (bucket).

So this works
{"mainPageSuffix": "NewHome/index.html"}.

In case the developers of the Google-cloud for web are listening to this... 
Even though the system picks up the index.html in a different folder, the images, jss etc are not pickedup. The current working directly still remains the home directory. (In the web case this could be relaxed to change the CWD based on where the mainpage suffix is pointing to. (just an opinion).